# Trigger is not called on update table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to make a trigger that updates the ID_ABONAMENT from the CONTRACTE table, when the ABONATI table is updated.

The problem is that the trigger is not called when I update a row in the ABONATI table.

Below is the trigger I made. Thank you in advance.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_CONTRACT_TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE ON ABONATI
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    id_abonat number;
    cod_abonament number;
BEGIN
    id_abonat := :new.ID_ABONAT;
    cod_abonament := :new.COD_ABONAMENT;
    UPDATE CONTRACTE SET COD_ABONAMENT = cod_abonament WHERE ID_ABONAT = id_abonat;
END;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should not be storing the same data in two different tables.  You should use `join` to look up the values when you query the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually have a completely different problem - the trigger is being called but it's updating every row, each time it's updating a column to itself.

```
set COD_ABONAMENT = cod_abonament

WHERE ID_ABONAT = id_abonat;
```

These are going to be evaluated as referring to the columns in your table rather than the variables. So this is going to evaluate to `true` for every row which has an `id_abonat` value that isn't null and set the column to itself. You need to either use a different variable name or fully specify it in your update statement.

I would just forget about using a user defined variable here and just use `:new.id_abonat` in your update statement as is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER UPDATE_CONTRACT_TRIGGER
AFTER UPDATE ON ABONATI
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE CONTRACTE SET COD_ABONAMENT = :new.COD_ABONAMENT WHERE ID_ABONAT = :new.ID_ABONAT;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.